# catkin build does not place executable in devel folder

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS1 noetic project with the following `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(ball_tracker_ros)

find_package(ball_tracker REQUIRED)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp prophesee_event_msgs)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/ball_tracker_ros.cpp)

# Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                      ball_tracker::ball_tracker)

target_include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
         $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include>
         $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
  PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

target_compile_options(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>>:
          -pipe
          -march=native
          -Wall
          -Wextra
          $<$<CONFIG:Release>:-O3>>
          $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-g
          -ggdb3
          -Og>>
          $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:
          $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/Od
          /Wall
          /Zi>>)
```

When I run `catkin build`, the executable (`ball_tracker_ros`)  is only in `build/ball_tracker_ros/` and not in `devel/lib/ball_ttracker_ros` (the folder `devel/lib/ball_ttracker_ros` does not exist at all). Since I don't get any compilation/linking errors/warning and the binary is in the build folder, compilation seems fine. In the same workspace I also have [this package](https://github.com/prophesee-ai/prophesee_ros_wrapper). The executable of this package end in `devel/lib/prophesee_ros_driver`. Therefore `catkin build` seems to work and I expect the problem witin the package `ball_tracker_ros`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382881/catkin-build-does-not-place-executable-in-devel-folder/) by [Andreas Ziegler](https://answers.ros.org/users/40817/andreas-ziegler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2021-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was to add

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp prophesee_event_msgs
)
```

before `add_executable(...)`.

I'm having a hard time with following the modern CMake style and the custom-made ROS CMake extensions (which appear to follow more the old CMake style). Does anyone have a best practice for this? ROS2 seems to follow more the modern CMake style.

---

Originally posted by [Andreas Ziegler](https://answers.ros.org/users/40817/andreas-ziegler/) with karma: 56 on 2021-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-23**:
Order matters with `CMakeLists.txt` and Catkin (actually, it always matters with CMake, it's just that with Catkin, it's easier to run into the kinds of hickups you encountered).

See [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt: Overall Structure and Ordering](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Overall_Structure_and_Ordering).

> I'm having a hard time with following the modern CMake style and the custom-made ROS CMake extensions (which appear to follow more the old CMake style). Does anyone have a best practice for this?

there isn't really anything to "best practice" here.

As you've noticed, Catkin was written (quite some time ago) to work-around some of the deficiencies of old CMake versions. As Catkin serves ROS 1, it's not seeing any new development. CMake is being developed, so there is going to be more-and-more divergence between what "modern CMake" suggests you do and what we do in "old CMake" `CMakeLists.txt` with Catkin.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-23**:
Note that "order matters with Catkin" has been discussed on this site quite some times.

To find previous Q&As, I recommend to use Google. Append `site:answers.ros.org` to your queries.